# How to give colors to only border-left in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, tailwind-css

I am trying to give blue colors to border-left in tailwind css

I tried to write codes as `border-l-8-blue`

however, it is a wrong code and it never works.

Here is my question, is there any ways to solely give colors to border-left??

instead of giving colors to all borders like `border-gray`

Comment: It looks like your doing the right thing according to the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-color#individual-sides .  Have you tried giving the class `.border-l-blue-800` to see if this works?

Answer (score 2):

To get the border only to the left side, use the below code in you Tailwind HTML

```
<div class="mx-auto w-12 h-12 sm:w-16 sm:h-16 bg-gray-400 border-l-2 border-gray-600"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-l-blue` actually works and what I made it wrong is tried to combine `border-l-blue` with `border-l-8` in one line as `border-l-blue-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add [border width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width)

```
<div class="border-4 border-l-indigo-500"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get border only to left side, use below syntax

```
<div class="border-4 border-blue-200 border-l-green-500">text</div>
```

[You can refer official Tailwind Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width#individual-sides)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However I already gave the default border-color as blue and what I would like to do is give border-left colors to green. Thus, border-left is green and other borders are blue

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="border-l-4 border-indigo-500 ..."></div`>

- border-l-4 : means the width of the left side border
- border-blue-500 : means the color of the left border

Comment: could you explain your code please for the benefit of future readers of this question? thanks in advance!